# How to have a sub view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am quite new with this MVC in ASP.NET. If I have a page which has Tournament class (in Detail mode) and underneath it has a list of PlayRoundHoles class which it's comes from stored procedure due to a complex query.

How do I achieve this to display this list under Tournament Detail View? I don't quite understand where this PlayRoundHoles sits in the Controller as well as the View?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ViewModel that contains all the required content for this page. In this case a ViewModel with a Tournament and List of PlayRoundHoles

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Tournament MyTournament { get; set; }
    public IList<PlayRoundHoles> MyPlayRoundHoles { get; set; }
}
```

Then your action method should return this strongly-viewed type.

```
public class TournamentController
{
    public ActionResult View(int tournamentId)
    {
        var t = //get tournament
        var p = //call sproc (may use the tournament id)

        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
        model.MyTournament = t;
        model.MyPlayRoundHoles = p;

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Your View can then look something like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyViewModel>" %>

//tournament details using Model.MyTournament
//play round holes details using Model.MyPlayRoundHoles
```

To improve on this you could create a PartialView that seperates the display of your PlayRoundHoles

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("MyPlayRoundHoles", Model.MyPlayRoundHoles); %>
```

Comment: @David: In regard to Model, I have already Linq to SQL and does this mean I have to create separate class called "MyViewModel" like above? Cause in my original Detail view page for Tournament i have: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Golfsys.Model.Tournament>" %> which the model is using Model.Tournament only correct?

Comment: If you already have a Tournament object from Linq2Sql then just use that instead of MyViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass instance of Tournament to View. And then render PlayRoundHoles in View.

for example see here http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx

Comment: I had a look on that one. In my case, PlayRoundHoles sits under Tournament Detail View. So it's like a sub view maybe?

Comment: What you mean by subview? I think you have details view for Tournament then just as part of those details you display PlayRoundHoles just like other Tournament fields. Maybe below other fields.

Comment: PlayRoundHoles is not field. It's class. The view between the Tournament class and PlayRoundHoles class are different. One is Detail View (Tournament) and the other one is a List View (PlayRoundHoles) on the same page.